# Would " -5 + Par" instead of "5 under Par" be understood/accepted?

Tags: terminology, golf

I'm currently writing a program involving Golf and my code's structure makes outputting "**-5 + par**" way easier (& shorter, in terms of code length required) than "**5 under par**". Now, is the former likely to be understood by the general golf player or is it so odd that I ought not to use it at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be understood... but I'd seriously question whether you've got your cost:benefit analysis right here - it would make your program look like it's written by someone who doesn't understand golf, and (as a professional programmer) it's two lines of code to output "5 under par" instead of "-5 + par".

Comment: I'd agree with you about the ratio if this were for a client, but it isn't. :)